# Unable to get ttc file work for fonts in android

Tags: android, fonts

I am trying to use .ttc font file in android without any success. 
What I have tried:
1-Added .ttc file to res/font folder
2-created font.xml and tried to get the reference of the specific font, as .ttc file contains multiple fonts.

But I am unable to get any auto suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cant use font from anywhere but assets folder, try adding it inside assets folder and write down this code

textView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/myFont.ttc"));

or use calligraphy library to add the font all over the project

[Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy)